# Draw many 3D lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a lot of Lines in a matplotlib 3D axes, but I am failing. Generally I have no clue where to find documentation about collections and artists...

This is what I've come up with so far

```
# start and stop are structured arrays
plt.ion
fig2 = plt.figure()
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

lines = []
for i in range(100):

    lines.append(Line3D(
        [
            start['x'][i], stop['x'][i]
        ],
        [
            start['y'][i], stop['y'][i]
        ],
        [
            start['z'][i], stop['z'][i]
        ],
        ))

#ax2.add_collection3d(Line3DCollection(lines))
col = Line3DCollection(lines)
ax2.add_collection3d(col)
```

A matplotlib figure does open, but as soon as I click into it, it rains exceptions.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for plot_wireframe. Have you gone through docs and tutorial? http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

Comment: Also, a minimal working example and a stack trace would help (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)